# Is there a way to enable anti-aliasing in Monogame under UWP?

Tags: windows, win-universal-app, monogame, fbx

I tried different approaches but nothing worked out.

So I have a UWP app where monogame is used. fbx models are imported.

Is this feature works under UWP at all?

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried many sample on the web site for use fbx and monogame in a uwp project. But no success. I can draw model only if without animations .. I hope somebody can help us please